# How to group days of the week together

Tags: time

I'm trying to create a business pamphlet in Japanese for a local business called Donut Day and I'm wondering how to list their Open hours in full sentences for a school project.

In english I would do something like

> Open
>
> Donut Day is open on Monday - 7am to 5pm
>
> Donut Day is open Tuesday through Saturday 6am to 5pm
>
> Donut Day is open on Sunday 6am to 3pm

So my question is, how do I say that Tuesday through Saturday part?  I googled a bit but couldn't find any answers that seemed reasonable that I could verify in any way with my level of comprehension.

Here is my attempt -

> 営業中
>
> ドーナツデイ は 月曜日 に 午前 7時 から午後 5時 まで 開いています。
>
> ドーナツデイ は 土曜日 から 土曜日 まで午前 6時 から 午後 5時 まで 営業しています。
>
> ドーナツデイ は 日曜日 の 午前 6時 から午後 3時 まで 営業しています。

Comment: Your times for Tues. – Sat. do not match between the English and Japanese.  Presumably the Japanese has the correct times?  Otherwise, why would you group Sunday by itself?  Also, you have several other inconsistencies in your question.  You say you want to list the hours "in full sentences", yet the English version itself is not full sentences.  You are also mixing 開いています and 営業しています.  You should pick one convention and stick to it.  I think you need to clarify exactly what you want (full sentences vs. simple information clauses) before we can help you effectively.

Comment: I mix the 2 conventions because I'm not sure if one is right in this context or one is wrong so I figured someone might mention one or the other.  Thanks for pointing out the hours discrepancy in the english part.  

I corrected the english to be in full sentences

Answer (score 4):

Important points to list their Open hours:

1. If **Donut Day** is the name of the shop or something like that, you should not use ド-ナツ デイ in the line to tell the Open hours. It sounds a special day for sale.
2. We usually use **24-hour clock** system on a signage.

**Original**

> Open
>   Donut Day is open on Monday - 7am to 5pm
>   Donut Day is open Tuesday through Saturday 6am to 5pm
>   Donut Day is open on Sunday 6am to 3pm

**Your attempt**

> 営業中
>   ド-ナツ デイ は 月曜日 に 午前 7時 から午後 5時 まで 開 いています
>   ド-ナツ デイ は 土曜日 から 土曜日 まで午前 6時 から 午後 5時 まで 営業しています
>   ド-ナツ デイ は 日曜日 の 午前 6時 から午後 3時 まで 営業し ています。

**My attempt as common Japanese sentences**

> 営業時間
>   ドーナツ・デイは、月曜日は、午前７時から午後５時まで営業しております。
>   ドーナツ・デイは、火曜日から土曜日までは、午前６時から午後５時まで営業しております。
>   ドーナツ・デイは、日曜日は、午前６時から午後３時まで営業しております。

**My attempt for a business pamphlet**

> ドーナツ・デイの営業時間は下記のようになっております。
>   月曜日　　　　　：午前７時から午後５時
>   火曜日から土曜日：午前６時から午後５時
>   日曜日および祝日：午前６時から午後３時

**My attempt for a signage**

> 営業時間
>   月曜　　　：7:00-17:00
>   火曜～土曜：6:00-17:00
>   日曜・祝日：6:00-15:00
>   　　　　ドーナツ・デイ

Comment: I agree, its for school its part of the requirements

Comment: @beginnerBinx: Search for the sample images on the Internet with the keyword of 営業｛えいぎょう｝時間｛じかん｝ not 営業中

Comment: Not very helpful, I need to answer it in full sentences which signage isn't going to do.